# How to use Terminfo's Capability type correctly. Are monad transformers the answer?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, terminfo

I've been struggling to simplify a small program using `System.Console.Terminfo`. I've gotten as far as `mappend`ing multiple `Capability` together, but whenever I need to evaluate them, I have to use `getCapability` and then use a `case` to pattern-match the resulting `Maybe`. The pattern is always the same

```
Just ... -> runTermOutput ...
Nothing -> return ()
```

so I think there must be a better way to do this. It seems to me that the pattern-matching is replacing `Maybe` with `IO`, so I thought it might be what monad transformers are for. Looking at the `Capability` definition,

```
> :i Capability
newtype Capability a
  = System.Console.Terminfo.Base.Capability (Terminal
                                             -> IO (Maybe a))
...
```

it does look similar to the `MaybeT` example I found here on StackOverflow, but the fact that it's a function throws me off. (Plus, I can't claim to understand monad transformers after reading just one example.)

Am I on the right track? Is there a different pattern that can help me avoid writing this `case` over and over again?

Here's `getCapability` type:

```
> :i getCapability 
getCapability :: Terminal -> Capability a -> Maybe a
...
```

Comment: It might help if you could post a bigger example of the pattern you don't like in context. But I wonder have you looked at what the `Monad` instance offers you? `(>>=) :: Capability a -> (a -> Capability b) -> Capability b`

Comment: @jberryman : Bind doesn't get me much in this instance as I'm trying to go from `Capability a -> IO ()` so that `main` can execute it. However, looking at this question, I think my actual issue is that `runTermOutput :: Terminal -> TermOutput -> IO ()` doesn't take a `Capability`. Having some function `runCapability :: Terminal -> Capability TermOutput -> IO ()` would probably get rid of my code repetition. Hmm, I think this question is a little too specific for StackOverflow. Can/Should it be changed to a more general, "How should Terminfo be used?"

Comment: @user2063685 Is there any reason you cannot write such a function? e.g. `\t c -> maybe (return ()) (\x -> runTermOutput ...) . getCapability t c` - just define it wherever you like and use it. Monad transformers won't help you here much - you could use a `MaybeT IO` transformer but unless you are using the `Maybe` logic elsewhere, it won't give you anything over simply defining the function you want. A question like "How should Terminfo be used?" would probably be much too broad.

Comment: @user2407038 Is there a way to move the `Capability` IO action to the IO unit return of `runCapability`? I would like to avoid `getCapability` as it uses [`unsafePerformIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/terminfo-0.4.0.2/docs/src/System-Console-Terminfo-Base.html#getCapability). I think this may be my actual question.

Comment: @user2063685 `Capability` is an abstract type - the constructor is not exported. Trying to 'move' the IO action out of the capability doesn't make any sense - there is no way to observe that it even contains an IO action without looking at the source. I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to use a function just because it uses `unsafePerformIO` (if you don't trust that the author knew what they were doing when they used it, do you trust any code they write?).

Comment: I just feel that if the IO actions all bubble up to `main`, it means the rest of the program is more pure, and the AST is better for it. In any case, I think your `\t c -> maybe (return ()) (\x -> runTermOutput t x) . (getCapability t c)` is the best answer I can see. This question is really a mess. I don't know if it would be for you to write up an answer, or just flag to close. Thank you to everyone that put up with me.

Comment: @user2063685 You are correct about isolating the IO in your program to one place, preferably `main`, but `Capability` is an abstract type - you shouldn't even need to know that it contains `IO`. The fact that it does is an implementation detail - the author could easily change the implementation without changing the interface. Trying to extract the IO from the `Capability` could violate some invariants set up by the author. Also, if my comment solves your problem feel free to make it into an answer and accept it (perhaps with some explanation as to how it solved your problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, the `Terminfo Capability` interface means that monad transformers are not the answer.

As user2407038 suggested, the `case` pattern can be avoided with the function,

```
\t -> maybe (return ()) (runTermOutput t) . (getCapability t)
  :: Terminal -> Capability TermOutput -> IO ()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mapM :: (Monad m, Traversable t) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
```

specializes not only to

```
mapM :: (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [b]
```

, but also to

```
mapM :: (a -> IO b) -> Maybe a -> IO (Maybe b)
```

. Same goes for `mapM_` and `for` and `for_` and `traverse` and `traverse_`.

Comment: `Capability` is not an instance of `Traversable`. How would I define the instance?

Comment: I meant that you use that instead of the case match. Hmm *rereads post and discussions* Why do you have more than one place where you want to convert the Capability into IO? (If it's just subsequent lines in the same main, where each step depends on the previous result, you could indeed use bind)

Comment: `Capability` actually supports `mappend` so that's what I've been using to string it together. I think your suggestion is equivalent.